# Setting CustomView in Android ActionBar; CustomView does not appear

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am trying to set a custom view in an ActionBar. I am using the support.v7 ActionBar - min API is 9. For some odd reason, I cannot get the custom view to appear in the ActionBar. Am I missing something painfully obvious? Any help appreciated.

Here is the layout I am inflating:

```
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="flsfjkelsjek"
  android:background="@color/black"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
/>
```

...Very simple, just a TextView for testing.

Here is the code to set this view as my custom ActionBar view:

```
TextView customView = (TextView) myInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_test_textview, null);
myActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
myActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
myActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
myActionBar.setCustomView(customView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Again, very simple and straightforward. I have tried many different varations on this, such as:

```
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

and have even tried that line along with all of the above. I've also tried with a TextView just created on the fly, rather than inflating one.

The custom view simply doesn't appear. When I check the value of

```
myActionBar.getCustomView()
```

it returns my TextView. However, the width of that TextView is 0. Does anyone have any idea why the CustomView is not showing up?

Comment: How are you getting your reference to myActionBar and where are you placing that code?

Comment: It's an ActionBarActivity; I'm using getSupportActionBar(). The code is in onActivityCreated

Comment: Put textview in LinearLayout

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gaurav. I tried that, but it didn't work either, sadly.

Comment: Can you post the style.xml for your ActionBar as well? Also, is it possible it's hidden, maybe trying to call myActionBar.show()?

Comment: I don't have an ActionBar style set in the theme I'm using. I tried calling show(), but no luck. Thanks though!